# Zabbix Agent 3.4.9 Active Monitoring Log file, Not supported: too many parameters

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to monitor the log file: /var/log/neo4j/debug.log

I'm looking for the text: Application threads blocked for ######ms

I have devised a regular expression for this as: Application threads blocked for (\d+)ms

We want to skip old info: add skip as mode

I want to pull out the number of MS so that the trigger will alert on blockages > 150ms.: \1 must be set as output parameter

I constructed the key as:

log[/var/log/neo4j/debug.log,Application threads blocked for (\d+)ms,,,skip,\1]

in accordance with

log[/path/to/file/file_name,< regexp >,< encoding >,< maxlines >,< mode >,< output >,< maxdelay >]

Type of Information is: Log
Update interval: 30s
History storage period: 90d
Timestamps appear in the log file as: 2018-10-03 13:29:20.460+0000

My timestamp appears as: yyyypMMpddphhpmmpss

I have tried a bunch of different things over the past week trying to get it to stop showing a "Too Many Parameters" error in the GUI without success. I'm completely lost at this point. We have 49 other items working correctly (all others are passive). Active checks are enabled in zabbix_agentd.conf.

Comment: What are the "bunch of different things", and what exactly happened with each of those?

Comment: Quotes, escaped quotes, different regexes, fewer parameters. Right now I have just log[/var/log/neo4j/debug.log,Application threads blocked for \d+ms] been like that about 30 mins, still says too many parameters.

Comment: Are you using Zabbix proxy? Also try doublequoting the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but it took me a while to solve this problem, so I'd like to share and hope it helps...

According to the [Zabbix official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) the parameters usage for log (and logrt) keys should be:

```
logrt[file_regexp,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>,<output>,<maxdelay>]
```

So, if we would use only the "skip" parameter, the item key should look like:

```
logrt[MyLogFile.log,,,,skip,,]
```

Nevertheless, it triggers the error "too many parameters".

In fact, to solve this issue I configured this key in my environment with only one coma after the  parameter, like this:

```
logrt["MyLogFile.log","MyFilter",,,skip,]
```

That's it... hope it helps someone else.